# Mongoid and mass assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, strong-parameters

I have the following mogoid document definition/class:

```
class Exercise
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :description, :type => String

  belongs_to :group

  validates_presence_of :name, :description
end
```

I then have the following controller and save method:

```
class ExercisesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @exercise = Exercise.create(params[:exercise])
    @exercise.save!
    respond_with @exercise
  end
end
```

This seems wrong to me and open to mass assignment problems.

How do people normally protect against this and would using the strong parameters gem be a good idea?

Comment: It's a good habit to explicitly use `attr_accessible` to whitelist attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you *should* use the strong_parameters gem, it will be the default mass-assignment protection in rails 4

Answer (score 0):

You can use attr_accessible as 'standard' protection. This of course still has the disadvantage that you expose a lot of fields to the interface, whereas you might want to expose only a few, but need to expose those fields in other controllers.